# Allow only letters on textbox, even if user copy+paste using jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I saw some code to allow only letters on textbox and I tried to use it in my code but it does not work and I don't know why. In jsfiddle it works perfectly.

I have this code:

```js
$("Nombre").on("keydown", function(event) {
  // Ignore controls such as backspace
  var arr = [8, 16, 17, 20, 32, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46];

  // Allow letters
  for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  if (jQuery.inArray(event.which, arr) === -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

$("Nombre").on("input", function() {
  var regexp = /[^a-zA-Z ]/g;
  if ($(this).val().match(regexp)) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regexp, ''));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" Maxlength=43 name="txtNombre" required>
```

Comment: Typo: `$("Nombre")` should be `$("#Nombre")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo: `$("Nombre")` should be `$("#Nombre")`. Don't forget the `#` before to let jQuery know that you want the element with the ID of Nombre.

```js
$("#Nombre").on("keydown", function(event) {
  // Ignore controls such as backspace
  var arr = [8, 16, 17, 20, 32, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46];

  // Allow letters
  for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  if (jQuery.inArray(event.which, arr) === -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

$("#Nombre").on("input", function() {
  var regexp = /[^a-zA-Z ]/g;
  if ($(this).val().match(regexp)) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regexp, ''));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" Maxlength=43 name="txtNombre" required>
```

Comment: damn it! I forgot it is JQuery not pure JS, thanks.